# International self publishing: where to start?

Tags: self-publishing, international

I decided that my book would be better suited to university students in other countries and some other select groups, such as Russian Christians. Some of the theory is considered very controversial and considered a strange topic in the US, but not in Europe.

I'm not against using a professional publisher, per se, but I have chosen this avenue for artistic reasons and I haven't needed one yet. I have no idea where to start to reach these markets. I give lectures in the US, but I'm unenthuzed about traveling to global events unless it would reach a very large market, such as a TV interview. (I wish...) Does anyone know about international self-publishing for academic and boutique markets?

Comment: You looking at digital publishing or traditional paper publishing...or both?

Comment: @James Only digital, also for artistic reasons, and I'm not going to do print even if there be some markets I can't reach. I don't think it should be too bad though.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has a near-global reach. To reach many countries, this is enough. Readers in some countries may find that your books are not available to them unless they open an Amazon US or Canadian account--this is especially true in the Middle East. As an indie publisher, there will be no warning that this is the case. Amazon has no presence in Russia, though, so you will have to find an alternative outlet. You can also sell through Apple's iTunes, but I do not know if they have a presence in Russia. It is currently not possible to sell Chinese-language texts through iTunes in China. China Mobile (the mobile phone company) is the largest purveyor of e-books in China. They take a hefty commission and there are limits on the amount you can charge for your books. I am tempted to say, "take a look at the International Literary Market Place" but unfortunately it's not all that helpful unless you want to find an agent. If you're looking for Russian rights buyers and translators it will be helpful. Make sure you look at volume II of the ILMP, that's where the listings are.

Selling into a foreign local market requires specialized knowledge. You might try to find a foreign publicist who is willing to work with you. What social media do the foreign university students use to communicate? Try to frame an advertising campaign using that media, as a start.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to self-publish exactly but there is wattpad.com or wattpad.co.uk (have a look there though I am not sure if it is what you are looking for). My account name on there is MISThomas.

Comment: Welcome to Writers. I see that you've posted two answers so far, and both link to Wattpad. Are you affiliated with the site?

Comment: I am just a member on it but if that is a problem then I can always remove my comments/answers. I am not sure about all the rules properly. Sorry. I am waiting to hear back about becoming an Ambassador on the site but that might be awhile.

Comment: ok, no problem as long as there's no issue in doing this